# gvim/vim/edit <filename>.py ends up in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

The error is described in the title.
It happens both with `edit`, `vim` and `gvim` on an `Ubuntu 20.04.3` machine with `Anaconda3` that ships with `Python 3.9.7`
The complete out is the following

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3'
  PYTHONPATH = '/home/yt75534/anaconda3/bin/python:/home/yt75534/vas/carla/CARLA_Shipping_0.9.11-62-gb0e63b71-dirty/LinuxNoEditor/PythonAPI/carla/dist/carla-0.9.11-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg'
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/yt75534/anaconda3/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3'
  sys.executable = '/home/yt75534/anaconda3/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/yt75534/anaconda3/bin/python',
    '/home/yt75534/vas/carla/CARLA_Shipping_0.9.11-62-gb0e63b71-dirty/LinuxNoEditor/PythonAPI/carla/dist/carla-0.9.11-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3/lib/python38.zip',
    '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8',
    '/home/yt75534/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f30b15cfa80 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Hints from Google suggest to unset the `PYTHONHONE` and `PYTHONPATH` variables. I tried those solutions, but the problem persists. I also tried with `Python3.8`. Same error.

Calling just`python3` from the bash works fine.

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: What do you get from `import sys; sys.executable` and where is the encodings module installed?

Comment: `sys.executable` gives: `/home/yt75534/anaconda3/bin/python`
Regardings the `encodings` module I don't know. I just installed Anaconda but there is a folder called `encodings` under `/home/yt75534/anaconda3/lib/python3.9`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself.

I was using a `.vimrc` that was developed for Windows and therefore there were many paths and references that make little or no-sense at all on Linux.
After I adjusted the `.vimrc` the problem disappeared.

May someone else could find this answer useful.